# Three.js vector3

Tags: three.js, разработка-игр, javascript

У меня почему-то не работает `vector3`

```
cube.position = new THREE.Vector3(0,2,0)
```

Даже так ничего не меняется.

Comment: @rishat, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Так и написано в логах, что Vector3 is undefined? 
Советую обратиться к логам и посмотреть, в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать

```
cube.position.set(0,2,0);
```